# How to remove Ref before leaving the screen in React / React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I would like to to remove Ref before leaving the screen in React / React native because it causes keyboard flickering on navigating back.

My code is:

```js
 // To focus on the input field when the page loads
    const privateNotesInput = useRef<AnimatedTextInputRef | null>(null);
    const focusTimeoutRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);

    useHtmlPaste(privateNotesInput);

    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            focusTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
                if (privateNotesInput.current) {
                    privateNotesInput.current.focus();
                }
                return () => {
                    if (!focusTimeoutRef.current) {
                        return;
                    }
                    clearTimeout(focusTimeoutRef.current);
                };
            }, CONST.ANIMATED_TRANSITION);
        }, []),
    );
    
    
     <InputWrapper
                        InputComponent={TextInput}
                        role={CONST.ROLE.PRESENTATION}
                        inputID={INPUT_IDS.PRIVATE_NOTES}
                        label={translate('privateNotes.composerLabel')}
                        accessibilityLabel={translate('privateNotes.title')}
                        autoCompleteType="off"
                        maxLength={CONST.MAX_COMMENT_LENGTH}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        autoGrowHeight
                        containerStyles={[styles.autoGrowHeightMultilineInput]}
                        defaultValue={privateNote}
                        value={privateNote}
                        onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                            debouncedSaveNote(text);
                            setNote(text);
                        }}
                        ref={(el: AnimatedTextInputRef) => {
                            if (!el) {
                                return;
                            }
                            privateNotesInput.current = el;
                            updateMultilineInputRange(privateNotesInput.current);
                        }}
                    />
```

For mobile Safari, updating the selection prop on an unfocused input will cause it to automatically gain focus and subsequent programmatic focus shifts (e.g., modal focus trap) to show the blue frame (:focus-visible style),
so we need to ensure that it is only updated after focus.

```
const updateMultilineInputRange: UpdateMultilineInputRange = (input, shouldAutoFocus = true) => {
    if (!input) {
        return;
    }

    if ('value' in input && input.value && input.setSelectionRange) {
        const length = input.value.length;


        const shouldSetSelection = !(Browser.isMobileSafari() && !shouldAutoFocus);
        if (shouldSetSelection) {
            input.setSelectionRange(length, length);
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        input.scrollTop = input.scrollHeight;
    }
};
```

If someone knows how to solve it then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Assuming `useFocusEffect` is like `useEffect`, you have a typo-level error. You need to return the cleanup function from your effect function, not from your `setTimeout` callback. Just move the `return` to after the assignment to `.current` (that is, after the `setTimeout` call). Alternatively, add a `useEffect` with a callback with no dependencies that removes the timer.

Answer (score 0):

move `return` to outside of setTimeout's callback.

```
    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            focusTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
                if (privateNotesInput.current) {
                    privateNotesInput.current.focus();
                }
            }, CONST.ANIMATED_TRANSITION);

            return () => {
                    if (!focusTimeoutRef.current) {
                        return;
                    }
                    clearTimeout(focusTimeoutRef.current);
                };
        }, []),
    );
```

This adjustment ensures that the cleanup function, which cancels the timeout, is properly returned when the component is unmounted or re-rendered.